# Document class with large margin on inner side

Tags: margins, document-classes

Is there a document class with a large margin on the inner side similar to how this book (**Anatomy book. Osteology**) looks:

[image]

I tried to modify the tufte classes, since I need a good support for notes/images in the margin, but the result became very buggy. I would prefer a document class which explicitly supports this style.

Comment: With the `geometry` package (https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Page_Layout#Odd_and_even_margins) ?

Comment: I need support for notes and images in the margin. I know `geometry` and `marginotes` but there are many small problems using these packages one has to take care of. The `tufte` document classes do a good job, but reversing the margin is not easy.

Comment: do you really mean "inner side"?  the second example shown has the wide margin on the left side on both pages.

Comment: I would prefer the inner side, but would be OK with an (asymmetric) always left side.